# C# Scratch Off Lottery Game: Loop isnt working starts glitching and its not displaying the total earnings

Tags: c#, loops

I'm in the process of finishing my scratch off game and just needed to create the loop for when the person says yes they wish to scratch off another ticket and it displays a new ticket with new numbers and prize. But when I enter "y", it starts to glitch on my console and just keeps loading the numbers up. When I hit "n" my text shows up but doesn't display the total amount of money earned after each ticket played. It now displays: "Total Winnings: $System.Action`1[System.Int32]". I'd assume totalWinners is supposed to be used somewhere but I'm not sure as to where either, this code was given to me to add on and improve.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

class LottoGame
        {

            private int[] numbers = new int[15]; // Array to hold random integers
            private int prize;
            private int winningNumber;
            private int totalWinnings;
            private int totalWinners;
            private string playerInput;
            // Constructor to Create a New Lotto Game

            public LottoGame()
            { 
                ShowRulesAndTicket();
                GenerateWinningNumber();
                GenerateRandomNumbers();
                GeneratePrizeValue();
                DisplayWinNumAndPrize();
                DisplayNumbers();
                CheckForWinner();
            

            }
        public string PlayerInput // Property to set or return player's move
        {
            get
            {
                return playerInput;
            }
            set
            {
                playerInput = value.ToUpper();
            }
        }
        public int[] Numbers
                {
                    get { return numbers; }
                }
            public int Prize
            {
                get { return prize; }
            }
            public int WinningNumber
            {
                get { return winningNumber; }
            }
            public int TotalWinnings
            {
                get { return totalWinnings; }
            }
            public void ShowRulesAndTicket()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("***************** Scratch-Off Lottery Game *******************");
                Console.WriteLine("Rules:");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n You are shown your *Winning Number* and the potential prize earnings");
                Console.WriteLine("You will be given 15 numbers to scratch off and test your luck.");
                Console.WriteLine("Multiply the prize value times number of matches to the winning number!");
                Console.WriteLine("GOOD LUCK!\n\n");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t Winning                Prize");
                Console.WriteLine("\t Number\n");
                Console.WriteLine($"          ?                       $?\n");
                for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
                {
                    if (x % 5 == 0)// Does line break to print 5 numbers per row
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.Write($"      ? ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine();
                Console.WriteLine("\n\n\tPress Enter to scratch off numbers....");
                Console.ReadLine();

            }
            public void GenerateWinningNumber()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                winningNumber = rand.Next(20) + 10; // Modify for desired range of numbers
            }
            public void GenerateRandomNumbers()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
                {
                    numbers[x] = rand.Next(20) + 10; // Modify for desired range of numbers
                }
            }
            public void GeneratePrizeValue()
            {
                Random rand = new Random();
                int num = rand.Next(3) + 1; // 3 random prizes generated.
                                        // Change these prize amounts as desired.
                if (num == 1)
                    prize = 5;
                else if (num == 2)
                    prize = 20;
                else
                    prize = 50;
            }
            public void DisplayWinNumAndPrize()
            {
                Console.Clear();
                Console.WriteLine("***************** Scratch-Off Lottery Game *******************");
                Console.WriteLine("\n\t Winning                Prize");
                Console.Write($"           {winningNumber}                   ${prize}\n");
            }
            public void DisplayNumbers()
            {
                for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
                {
                    if (x % 5 == 0)// Does line break to print 5 numbers per row
                        Console.WriteLine();
                        Console.Write($"      {numbers[x]} ");
                }
                    Console.WriteLine();
                    Console.WriteLine("You won: $" + prize);
        }

            public int CheckForWinner()
            {
                int numberOfMatches = 0;
                for (int x = 0; x < 15; x++)
                {
                    if (numbers[x] == winningNumber)
                        numberOfMatches++;
                }
                return numberOfMatches;
                UpdateTotalWinnings(numberOfMatches * prize);
            }
            public void UpdateTotalWinnings(int val)
            {
                totalWinnings += val;
                Console.WriteLine("Total Winnings is: " + totalWinnings);
            }
        }
internal class Program
{
    private static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        bool gameLoop = true;
        LottoGame lottoGame = new LottoGame();
        while (gameLoop)
        {
            if (lottoGame.PlayerInput != "Y" && lottoGame.PlayerInput != "N")
             {
                Console.WriteLine("Do you want to scratch off another ticket Y/N?: ");
                lottoGame.PlayerInput = Console.ReadLine();
                lottoGame.PlayerInput = lottoGame.PlayerInput.ToUpper();
             }
                if (lottoGame.PlayerInput == "Y")
                {
                    gameLoop = true;
                    lottoGame.DisplayWinNumAndPrize();
                    lottoGame.DisplayNumbers();
                    continue;
                }
                else if(lottoGame.PlayerInput == "N")
                {
                    gameLoop = false;
                    lottoGame.CheckForWinner();
                    Console.WriteLine("Total Winnings: $" + (lottoGame.UpdateTotalWinnings));

                }
                else
                {
                    Console.WriteLine("Invalid input. Please enter Y or N. ");
                }
                Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to continue.");
                Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Good: you have posted the code. Bad: that code doesn't compile.

Answer (score 1):

You don't appear to be clearing out PlayerInput between rounds, so when it loops around, it already contains Y or N.  I don't really think you need that first if statement.  If player input is "N" it should never get there because gameloop is false and if player input is "Y", the way you have it written it will never prompt for another input. I would change this:

```cs
if (lottoGame.PlayerInput != "Y" && lottoGame.PlayerInput != "N")
  {
    Console.WriteLine("Do you want to scratch off another ticket Y/N?: ");
    lottoGame.PlayerInput = Console.ReadLine();
    lottoGame.PlayerInput = lottoGame.PlayerInput.ToUpper();
  }
```

to just this

```cs
Console.WriteLine("Do you want to scratch off another ticket Y/N?: ");
lottoGame.PlayerInput = Console.ReadLine();
lottoGame.PlayerInput = lottoGame.PlayerInput.ToUpper();

// PlayeInput Check below this
```

Comment: ok, I see what youre referring to and see where my issues lied. But is there a reason my total winnings arent showing up after the game ends?

Comment: @DeasjiaShannon Yes, you are writing UpdateTotalWinnings to the console, but that is a method with no return type.  It's likely outputting it as a method group object because you aren't calling the method either.